# PhpStorm + Git + 3 VPS + many files sync

Tags: git, intellij-idea, synchronization, phpstorm, vps

I have a project in PhpStorm. I have 3 VPS running (one for remote dev, one for local dev, another for production).

There are over 30K files in a project it take hours to sync, mostly PHP hangs. So, either I sync them by some portions. Or preferably I exclude in PhpStorm folders which not need to sync for sure when syncing.
When I need to work on several independent tasks simultaneously, I have to manually set "excluded" folders in PhpStorm for every task when I need to sync with VPS.

I started to use Git recently (I'm a newbaby yet here), its branches approach is good. I tried to manipulate with `./.idea/{projectname}.iml` file. Since it contains excluded folders list I added it to Git tracking in order to make it "change" through git for different branches. But not helpful, when PhpStorm switches between the branches `{projectname}.iml` is not updated/replaced.

I am looking for a best practice advise from experienced developers. What is the best practice solution for such a case?